# Keep image popup within browser display area

Tags: jquery

I have a grid of images, and a hover pop up larger image. I position the images with the following code, however pop ups are out of the display area on the left. How do I keep the popup images within the browser display?

```
 $(function() {
     $('.popup_button').hover(function() {
        var win=$(this).find('.popup:visible');
        if(win.length>0) {
            var screenwidth=$('wrapper').width();
            var width=win.width();
            var pos=win.position();
            var rightpos=width+pos.left;
            if(rightpos>screenwidth) {
                var moveleft=rightpos-screenwidth;
                win.css('margin-left','-'+moveleft+'px');
            } else {
                win.css('margin-left','px');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is **wrapper**?? Is it a class or id. Correct it first.

Comment: First of all, if `wrapper` is a class then you need to access it like a class which means putting a `.` in the selector: `$('.wrapper')`. Secondly, can you add some html and any other relevant javascript to this post? An example in a jsfiddle would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Not sure why I put wrapper (which is a class), but it gave the effect (except for moving images out of view to left), whereas body or section didn't.

Comment: adding the .wrapper breaks the effect of moving the popup.

Comment: I am just looking how to keep the popup to stay within the window. I can move it with css, so the above script I don't actually need.

Comment: Could you add more code, especially a sample of the html that this is applying to? Until we have more info it is really difficult to understand how this all is working and where it's going wrong. I actually think I know why adding the `.` breaks it and without it the placement is wrong, but I'd like to confirm my suspicion with more code.